# How to resume file download using read.csv() in R

Tags: r, read.csv

I am reading a big csv using read.csv() in R. But if internet connection is lost then the download stops and error is shown.

Is there any way by which if internet connection is lost, download will be paused say for predefined 300 seconds and when connection comes, it will again resume the download automatically ?

Comment: I couldn't find a way within R, but you can use a command-line, for example `wget -c http://...` or `curl -C - http://...`.

Comment: But I have to implement within a large R script.

Comment: My only suggestion is to look at the `curl` package and see if you can set and `handle` parameters to allow continuation. I looked briefly when I saw your question and didn't see one, but then again I was side-tracked by work and had to set it aside. Good luck.